# How to decompress invocation API response In Java?

Tags: java, string, api, gzip, response

I want to decompress an API response (header : `Accept-encoding=gzip`).

Here are the lines I tried but always failed due to:

> `java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format`

```java
String entity = response.readEntity(String.class); 
// When I print "entity" I will get Compress message as below:
��{o�ʒ��
���c^MC��������ut4"�ms���fWGگ�_o?�V�G�ę�=�PF�3��i�������ɚ���G�[�eEA����$��M�(�rW�nk��97�m�r��6�$�$T�a^ZaIj�"�5U�4�����4:oW�C{�-��A�c0�hސ�*l���JP�ƚ.������t�
}ˏ�r�kIxjk��!���m�0��Z�9    ���r[�����6!٦^fQ�X_d)hބe���m��\RP�Y��Xg�:�F�IEE�5]U��f�\jϋ�?N�ߖ�<�κ;�+��j�xQ�{����40�]4N�NOib�=o(r�mL�rLϱ�>Rۖ�l4
{2jʁk��f�*�љw��a�l���������^�V�a�ӱ���w[2�V>n��'��n���;�ȧ�#�p-ch}<>�9>�IB�~X��X���=��lz9)H��2#O?�R����*�����q�c�V�t����c�ܩ<��A��[���4
��

byte[] input = entity.getBytes(); 

// helper method
public static String decompress(byte[] compressed) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed);
        // Always failed at "GZIPInputStream" line due to java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format        
        GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(bis); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gis, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        br.close();
        gis.close();
        bis.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: If response can provide byte[] directly use that rather than stream->String->byte[], or if it can give you InputStream then change to decompress(InputStream bis) instead. Also you will lose line breaks in the output when it is converted back to a String (if there was a UTF-8 String in the stream)

Comment: thank you for your reply. It does not return String or byte. It is an exciting method and it returns List<JsonNode>.